# Module not found "solana.publickey"

Tags: python, solana

```
import solana
import pyserum
from pyserum.connection import conn
from pyserum.market import Market
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

# Connect to the Solana devnet
http_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
connection = conn("https://api.devnet.solana.com")

# Market address we will interact with
market_address = "AMKpY1FVmZTRUDqCGyJvDBEYYqQwoqscu9J65MVXhkcT"

# Fetch the market using the updated Pubkey reference
market = Market.load(connection, Pubkey.from_string(market_address))

# Fetch the order book
order_book = market.load_order_book()
bids = order_book.bids()
asks = order_book.asks()

# Print the best bid and ask
print(f"Best bid: {bids.get_best()}, Best ask: {asks.get_best()}")
```

This is the code I am running, and here is the error message I am getting. I can't figure this out. I have tried some other things and from another post about this issue on here I made some changes to the "Fetch the market using the updated pubkey reference" and that didn't solve the problem either.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 3
      1 import solana
      2 import pyserum
----> 3 from pyserum.connection import conn
      4 from pyserum.market import Market
      5 from solana.rpc.api import Client

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyserum/connection.py:6
      3 import requests
      5 from solana.rpc.api import Client as conn  # pylint: disable=unused-import # noqa:F401
----> 6 from solana.publickey import PublicKey
      7 from .market.types import MarketInfo, TokenInfo
      9 LIVE_MARKETS_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/project-serum/serum-ts/master/packages/serum/src/markets.json"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solana.publickey'
```

I'm using the following:

```
PySerum version: 0.5.0a0    
Solana version: 0.32.0
Solders version: 0.20.0
```

Comment: I see—it appears that the issue is that your version of `pyserum` currently imports from `solana.publickey`, which is deprecated syntax. Can you check if your versions of `pyserum` and `solana` are compatible? If not, you may need to downgrade the latter and/or upgrade the former.

Comment: @nathanliang I'm not sure I'm using

PySerum version: 0.5.0a0
Solana version: 0.32.0
Solders version: 0.20.0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out—it is indeed a dependency issue. If you go to the requirements file in the `pyserum` documentation, you'll see that the only compatible `solana` version is `0.16.0`.

So, you're going to have to downgrade `solana` for this to work—I'd recommend doing this inside a dedicated `venv` or `conda` environment if you aren't already using one. You'll need to run:

```
pip install solana=="0.16.0"
```

That being said, it appears some of your other syntax is outdated; here's some updated code that I was able to successfully run (note the new connection URL and bid / ask retrieval):

```
import solana
import pyserum
from pyserum.connection import conn
from pyserum.market import Market
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

# Connect to the Solana devnet
http_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
connection = conn("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/") 

# Market address we will interact with
market_address = "9wFFyRfZBsuAha4YcuxcXLKwMxJR43S7fPfQLusDBzvT"

# Fetch the market using the updated Pubkey reference
market = Market.load(connection, Pubkey.from_string(market_address))

# Fetch the order book
bids = market.load_bids()
asks = market.load_asks()

# Get the best bid and ask
# For bids, the best bid is the highest price, so we use max.
# For asks, the best ask is the lowest price, so we use min.
best_bid = max(bids, key=lambda order: order.info.price) if bids else None
best_ask = min(asks, key=lambda order: order.info.price) if asks else None

# Print the best bid and ask
if best_bid:
    print(f"Best bid:\n Price: {best_bid.info.price}, Size: {best_bid.info.size}")
else:
    print("No bids available.")

if best_ask:
    print(f"Best ask:\n Price: {best_ask.info.price}, Size: {best_ask.info.size}")
else:
    print("No asks available.")
```